# Monkeypatch with instance method

Tags: python, pandas, partials, monkeypatching, functools

I'm trying to monkeypatch how `pandas` Panel's slicing (`__getitem__`).  This is straightforward to do with a basic function, foo.

```
from pandas import Panel
Panel.__getitem__ = ORIGINAL_getitem


def newgetitem(panel, *args, **kwargs):
    """ Append a string to return of panel.__getitem__"""
    out = super(Panel, panel).__getitem__(*args, **kwargs)
    return out+'custom stuff added'

Panel.__getitem__ = newgetitem
```

Where`ORIGINAL_getitem` is storing the original Panel method.  I'm trying to extend to the case where `foo()` is not a function, but an instance method of an object, `Foo`.  For example:

```
class Foo:

    name = 'some name'

    def newgetitem(self, panel, *args, **kwargs):
        """ Append a string to return of panel.__getitem__,
        but take attributes from self, like self.name
        """
        out = super(Panel, panel).__getitem__(*args, **kwargs)
        return out+'custom stuff added including name' + self.name
```

`Foo.foo()` must access the attribute `self.name`.  Therefore, the monkeypatched function would need a reference to the Foo instance somehow, in addition to the Panel.  How can I monkepatch panel with `Foo.foo()` and make self.name accessible?

The switching between the monkey patched function happens in another method, `Foo.set_backend()`

```
class Foo:

    name = 'some name'

    def foo(self):
        return 'bar, called by %s' % self.name

    def set_backend(self, backend):
        """ Swap between new or original slicing."""
        if backend != 'pandas':
            Panel.__getitem__ = newgetitem            
        else:
            Panel.__getitem__ = ORIGINAL_getitem
```

What I really need is for `newgetitem` to maintain a reference to `self`.

### Solution Attempts

So far I've tried taking making `newgetitem()` a pure function, and using partial functions to pass a reference to self in.  This doesn't work.  Something like:

```
import functools

def newgetitem(foo_instance, panel, *args, **kwargs):
    ....

class Foo:

    ...
    def set_backend(self, backend):
        """ Swap between new or original slicing."""
        if backend != 'pandas':
            partialfcn = functools.partial(newgetitem, self)
            Panel.__getitem__ = partialfcn            
        else:
            Panel.__getitem__ = ORIGINAL_getitem
```

But this doesn't work.  A reference to self is passed, but no access from the calling Panel possible. That is:

```
 panel['50']
```

Passes a reference to `Foo`, not to `Panel`.

**Yes, I know this is bad practice, but it's just a workaround for the time-being.**

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`patch` from mock framework](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#patch) to handle your case. Even it is designed for testing, its primary work is monkey patching in defined contex.

Your `set_backend()` method could be:

```
def set_backend(self, backend):
    if backend != 'pandas' and self._patched_get_item is None:
        self._patched_get_item = patch("pandas.Panel.__getitem__", autospec=True, side_effect=self._getitem)
        self._patched_get_item.start()
    elif backend == 'pandas' and self._patched_get_item is not None:
        self._patched_get_item.stop()
        self._patched_get_item = None
```

That will work either when `self._getitem` is a method or a reference to a function.

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this is to create a closure (a function with reference to names other than locals or globals). A simple closure:

```
def g(x):
    def f():
        """f has no global or local reference to x, but can refer to the locals of the 
        context it was created in (also known as nonlocals)."""
        return x
    return f

func = g(1)
assert func() == 1
```

I don't have pandas on my system, but it works much the same with a `dict`.

```
class MyDict(dict):
    pass

d = MyDict(a=1, b=2)
assert d['a'] == 1

class Foo:

    name = 'name'

    def create_getitem(fooself, cls):
        def getitem(self, *args, **kwargs):
            out = super(cls, self).__getitem__(*args, **kwargs)
            return out, 'custom', fooself.name 
            # Above references fooself, a name that is not defined locally in the 
            # function, but as part of the scope the function was created in.
        return getitem

MyDict.__getitem__ = Foo().create_getitem(MyDict)
assert d['a'] == (1, 'custom', Foo.name)

print(d['a'])
```

Answer (score 0):

The basics of monkey patching are straightforward but it can quickly become tricky and subtle, especially if you're aiming at finding a solution that would work for both Python 2 and Python 3.

Furthermore, quickly hacked solutions are usually not very readable/maintenable, unless you manage to wrap the monkey patching logic nicely.

That's why I invite you to have a look at a library that I wrote especially for this purpose. It is named Gorilla and you can find it on [GitHub](https://github.com/christophercrouzet/gorilla).

In short, it provides a cool set of features, it has a wide range of unit tests, and it comes with [a fancy doc](http://gorilla.readthedocs.org/) that should cover everything you need to get started. Make sure to also check the FAQ!